# Changing value in entire column of a CSV file using awk

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have CSV file like example below. I wish to change value of mail in every line for the same mail with `awk`. I used

```
awk -F ";" '{$18=firstname.lastname@testdata.invali} {print}' example_source_20180619.csv > erm.csv
```

but got error invalid statement

```
  PNR;GES-SL-SAP;VERT-KANAL-SL-SAP;DSTNR-SAP;BTRBL-FKT;SCHWPKT-TAETIG-SL;SCHWPKT-TAETIG-TXT;BTRBL-TITEL-TXT;ANREDE;NAME;VORNAME;STRASSE;PLZ;ORT;DIENST-TEL-NR;TELEFAX-NR;MOBIL-TEL-NR;E-MAIL-ADR;INTERNET-ADR;P34F-KZ;HD-ANL-BER-KZ;VERT-KANAL-SL;
0000000;0010;2100 ;00602;Referent                      ;99;Sonstige/kein Schw.           ;ohne Titel                    ;Sir           ;John                       ;Doe                     ;Paul-Keller-Str. 21           ;92318;Neumarkt i.d.OPf.       ;phone;0941/phone;;mail@mail.com;http://web.de ;NO;NO;
```

Comment: Good that your showed your attempts which you have put to solve your issue, please post sample input and expected sample output too in your post.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F ";" '{OFS=";"; $18="firstname.lastname@testdata.invali"; print;}'
```

1. Put strings inside `"`.
2. Separate commands using `;`.
3. Set the output separator also to `;` so the output is similar to the input.
4. I guess theres no point in substituting the email address in the first line, so I added a small if below:

```
awk -F ";" '{ OFS=";"; if (NR != 1) { $18="firstname.lastname@testdata.invali"; } print; }'
```